# How to get the geometry of a specific pixel in an image.RGBA or any other type?

Tags: image, go

I wish there was something like image.Point struct but instead it was pixel based, if that makes sense.

Say I have loaded and decoded an `image.RGBA` with size(bounds) of 300x300. How can I get the exact coordinate of the middle of the image in `image.Point` or `fixed.Point26_6`?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Do you want the coordinates (x, y) of the center point of the image? Or the color at the center?

Comment: @icza I want the coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`image.RGBA`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#RGBA) is a concrete implementation of the general [`image.Image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) interface.

It has an `Image.Bounds()` method:

```
// Bounds returns the domain for which At can return non-zero color.
// The bounds do not necessarily contain the point (0, 0).
Bounds() Rectangle
```

Important to note that the top-left corner of the image might not be at the zero point `(0, 0)` (although generally it is).

So the geometry of the image is handed to you as a value of [`image.Rectangle`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Rectangle):

```
type Rectangle struct {
    Min, Max Point
}
```

To handle the general case (where top-left might not be `(0, 0)`), you have to account both the `Min` and `Max` points to to calculate the center point:

```
cx := (r.Min.X + r.Max.X)/2
cy := (r.Min.Y + r.Max.Y)/2
```

Another solution is to use [`Rectangle.Dx()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Rectangle.Dx) and [`Rectangle.Dy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Rectangle.Dy):

```
cx := r.Min.X + r.Dx()/2
cy := r.Min.Y + r.Dy()/2
```

And there is an [`image.Point`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Point) struct type. To get the center point as a value of `image.Point`:

```
cp := image.Point{(r.Min.X + r.Max.X) / 2, (r.Min.Y + r.Max.Y) / 2}
```

Or:

```
cp := image.Point{r.Min.X + r.Dx()/2, r.Min.Y + r.Dy()/2}
```

See this example:

```
r := image.Rect(0, 0, 300, 100)
fmt.Println(r)
cp := image.Point{(r.Min.X + r.Max.X) / 2, (r.Min.Y + r.Max.Y) / 2}
fmt.Println(cp)

cp = image.Point{r.Min.X + r.Dx()/2, r.Min.Y + r.Dy()/2}
fmt.Println(cp)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wopiR8LWCp)):

```
(0,0)-(300,100)
(150,50)
(150,50)
```

Comment: Thanks. My confusion was because a function within my code was converting my ints `x`, `y` to `fixed.Int26_6`. I had to shift left `x << 6` to make things work.